# How to send a POST request response back to client (React component)?

Tags: express, reactjs

I'm using React to send a post request to my express server which then returns a response, like so:

```
app.post('/api/games', function(req, res) {
   return res.json();
});
```

Before I use that response to persist it to a database, I want to be able to see everything within that response. When I console.log it from the server, I get a long list of the JSON object printed, but would ideally like something closer to Chrome's dev tools console where I can click through and inspect everything. How can I send this response JSON back to my React component so that I can console.log it in in the browser?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) in order to debug your express API.

It uses Chrome Dev Tools so you'll feel like you are debugging your client side!

Comment: Thanks, this was actually super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, a `request` comes in, and the `response` goes out.

on a request, the `req.body` and `req.params` will contain the body/params of the request.

To respond to a request, use the `res.json({someJSONHere})` or you can also `res.send({someJson})`

You can also `console.log` inside the server and watch output on the terminal

```
app.post('/api/games', function(req, res) { 
 console.log(req.params)
 console.log(req.body)
 return res.json(
   Object.assign({}, req.body, req.params)
 );
});
```

[Express request/response Documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view your response in the client-tier here are some of the things you can do using the GoogleChrome asides from the console

1 [Use React Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en)

2 I like using [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) for viewing and manipulating request/response